# How to allow Mac to connect to PPTP VPN using Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: macos, vpn

PPTP support in macOS Sierra is dropped, check this for [information](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206844), there are no free alternatives.

I know I can easily configure my Raspberry Pi to connect to VPN server using PPTP. Is there any way where I can tweak my Raspberry Pi (which is already connected to PPTP VPN), to allow my MacBook to connect to it (using Wi-Fi, Ethernet), so that I can access my server with the MacBook?

I am assuming there should be way where traffic from my MacBook can be redirected to Raspberry Pi, which behaves as a VPN server which is already connected to my server?

I may be completely wrong in my assumption :(

**Note: I have posted this question in ASK different site, but unfortunately they have declared it as a  "[duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250522/connection-l2tp-via-ipsec-to-vpn-as-pptp-vpn-no-longer-supported-on-macos-sierra)" which is not in any possible sense :(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your Pi to route between the VPN interface and its local network interface and then configure the Mac to use the Pi as a gateway to the VPN.

You'll need to know address of the network you're connecting to when you connect your VPN; if it's not obvious from the configuration you can run `ip route` on the Pi before and after connecting and see what new routes were added. I'll use 10.128.0.0/16 (netmask 255.255.0.0) as an example.

On your Pi, once the VPN is connected, you need only enable packet forwarding with

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.
```

To configure your Mac to use your Pi as the gateway to the VPN network you use (with 192.168.10.11 as the example Pi address):

```
route add 10.128.0.0 192.168.10.11 255.255.0.0
```

(The parameters are network address, gateway address and netmask of the network address.)

If you have difficulties, the easiest way to debug is to use `tcpdump` on your Pi. You can have it running twice in different windows with different `-i` options to look at the VPN interface and the LAN interface at the same time and see what's arriving and leaving on each.